# Android Firebase connection handling

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase and I want to handle the moment when you downloaded the application, turned off the Internet, launched the application and the database did not load. Just to handle the lack of Internet is not quite what I need. It is necessary to process exactly the fact that the data did not load or the connection did not pass, or some method did not start.

I have no idea how to solve it :(